# Get fullname of downloaded Python wheel, without merely watching the filesystem

Tags: shell-script, shell, python, pip

My script downloads a "continuum-transfunctioner" wheel from a pypi server as follows:

```
python3 -m pip download continuum-transfunctioner -i https://pypi.acme.com:8080/simple  --no-dependencies
# Downloads: continuum-transfunctioner-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
```

How can I get the full name of the wheel downloaded? I know I can watch the file system but surely there's a better way. Right?